# LARAVEL::How to Display the requested date range on the another blade page

Tags: php, laravel

I have the function which requested `start date` and `End date` from my blade form, then it dowbload the report from that date range

so i want to display those date range `start date` and `End date` on top of second page.

CONTROLLER

```
       public function stockIssued(Request $request) {

    $startdate=$request->startdate;
   $enddate=$request->enddate;
    //issued
   $stockIssued=DB::select(DB::raw(" SELECT 
    products.id, 
    products.name,  
    (select ifnull(sum(loadings.qty),0) from loadings where loadings.pid=products.id and 
              DATE(loadings.created_at)  BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('$startdate','%m/%d/%Y') AND 
              STR_TO_DATE('$enddate','%m/%d/%Y')  ) as total_loadings_specific_date
    from products"));

$pdf = PDF::loadView('report.issuedreportprint',compact('stockIssued'));

return $pdf->download('issuedreport.pdf'); 
// return view('report.issuedreport',compact('stockIssued'));
//
  }
```

Blade view (where i want to display those date on top of my report)

```
     </head>
     <body>
    <?php
    $startdate = $request->old('startdate');
      $enddate = $request->old('enddate');

      echo "<p>From:'$startdate'  To:'$enddate'</p>"

  ?>
 <table  width="90%" border="1"  align="center" style="margin-top: 20px;margin-bottom: 2px; margin- 
   left:10px; margin-right:10px; " >

  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Items Name</th>
      <th>Total Qty</th>
     </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    @foreach($stockIssued as $dt)
    <tr>
      <td>{{$dt->name}}</td>
      <td>{{$dt->total_loadings_specific_date ??0 }}</td>
      </tr>
    @endforeach
  </tbody>
</table>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understanding you want to pass the dates to the pdf file you are generating you can do it as:

```
$startdate = $request->startdate;
$enddate = $request->enddate;

$pdf = PDF::loadView('report.issuedreportprint',compact('stockIssued', 'startdate', 'enddate'));
```

Then in the blade file you can access it directly:

```
<p> From:{{ $startdate }}  To: {{ $enddate }} </p>
```

Comment: @EmmaMfinanga Pls. do up votes, if my answer helped you to solved your problem, it will be appreciated.